# Spring MVC Mapping problem

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have what I thought was a simple Spring MVC app.  However, I can seem to set the requestMappings correctly.  What's strange is that the logs show that the url is mapped to the proper controller, yet the Dispatcher cant seem to find it at runtime.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated:

Log

```
INFO: Mapped URL path [/app/index] onto handler     [com.noisyair.whatisayis.web.MainController@420a52f]
Jan 11, 2010 2:14:21 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/app/index.*] onto handler [com.noisyair.whatisayis.web.MainController@420a52f]
Jan 11, 2010 2:14:21 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/app/index/] onto handler [com.noisyair.whatisayis.web.MainController@420a52f]
Jan 11, 2010 2:14:21 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/app/tags/{tag}] onto handler [com.noisyair.whatisayis.web.SearchByTagController@7b3cb2c6]
Jan 11, 2010 2:14:21 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/app/tags/{tag}.*] onto handler [com.noisyair.whatisayis.web.SearchByTagController@7b3cb2c6]
Jan 11, 2010 2:14:21 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/app/tags/{tag}/] onto handler [com.noisyair.whatisayis.web.SearchByTagController@7b3cb2c6]
Jan 11, 2010 2:14:21 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'wisi': initialization completed in 237 ms
Jan 11, 2010 2:14:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
INFO: Container org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/] has already been started
Jan 11, 2010 2:14:41 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/app/index] in DispatcherServlet with name 'wisi'
```

Web.xml file

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- The Spring MVC framework handles all of this stuff.  Just pass it along -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>wisi</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>wisi</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Controller class:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

@Autowired
private LearningEntryService learningEntryService;

public LearningEntryService getLearningEntryService() {
    return learningEntryService;
}

public void setLearningEntryService(LearningEntryService learningEntryService) {
    this.learningEntryService = learningEntryService;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/app/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView sayHello(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    List<LearningEntry> le = learningEntryService.getLearningEntries();
    model.put("learningEntries", le);
    return new ModelAndView("main", model);
}
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You shouldn't duplicate "/app" in both `@RequestMapping` and `<url-pattern>`. That is, your `sayHello` now is mapped to "/app/app/index". You can write

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

(Or you can declare `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` bean in your config and set its `allwaysUseFullPath` property to `true` to override default behavior)