# Spring servlet mapping - no css or jsp!

Tags: java, spring, servlets, url-mapping

I read over [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129876/using-spring-mapping-to-root-in-web-xml-static-resources-arent-found/2129960#2129960) post, which is similar to my issue, but had no luck solving the problem:

Basically I used to have the following servlet-mapping in my `web.xml`:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/index.html</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>/channel1</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>/channel2</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This worked perfectly until I needed to map the following url:

```
/channel1/{id}/{random_text}
```

Where {id} is a numeric ID value of my objects and {random_text} is just there just for "freindly urls".  I managed to get this to work using the `@RequestMapping` in my controller as well as the `@PathVariable` to pull the variables from the URL.

However, the only way I managed to get the new URL to map successfully is be adding

```
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

to my `web.xml` at the bottom of my servlet-mappings. BUT, when I do this, all my other pages (`/channel1`, `/channel2`) display without access to the static content (css, jsp etc); I get a `No mapping found for HTTP request with URI` for the static files.  I tried various combinations of mappings as suggested in the link I posted, but nothing worked.  Any help would be great!!!

**Update**: my RequestMapping in the controller looks as follows (if it helps solve the problem at all..):

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/channel1/{id}", "/channel1/{id}/{text}" })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized what the issue is (probably my fault for not elaborating on my @RequestMapping setup in the Controller earlier):

In my `web.xml` I had a url-pattern:

```
<url-pattern>/channel/*</url-pattern>
```

Also, in my controller I used the following mapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/channel1/{id}", "/channel1/{id}/{text}" })
```

The problem was that I was duplicating the `/channel1` portion.  I randomly (luckily) came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045384/spring-mvc-mapping-problem/2045422#2045422) post explaining this issue.

Long story short, when I changed my mapping in the controller to the following it works perfectly:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/{id}", "/{id}/{text}" })
```

Answer (score 3):

> This worked perfectly until I needed to map the following url:
>
> ```
> /channel1/{id}/{random_text}
> ```

This is to be covered by `url-pattern` of `/channel1/*`. Note the trailing `/*`. The `url-pattern` of `/channel1` would not accept anything more in the pathinfo behind, it would only accept the exact URL and the optional query parameters.

Comment: Yes I tried this (just tried again), and I get a 'No mapping found...' error when visiting the url...

Comment: Then either the test/deploy was incorrect, or there's more in the mappings which coillides and/or got precedence.

Comment: My mappings are exactly as I posted in the question.  Is there a particular order that is necessary?  Also I'm not sure that the deploy is at fault because everything else gets mapped properly except for the new url that I need.

Comment: Also the `url-pattern` of `/`? This basically means "cover everything". Remove it from Spring dispatcher.

Comment: Yea I only added the '/' mapping as a test.  This was the only way I could get the url to map properly (with the side effect of no access to my css, jsp...files). I did try "/channel1/*" (WITHOUT the '/' mapping) and it did not work.  I am not sure why..

Comment: To the point: the URL's of static files should **not** match any of the `url-pattern` values of the Spring dispatcher servlet. If you have static files in `/channel1` folder, then this problem will indeed occur. Move them outside, e.g. `/static` or `/channel1static` or so.

Comment: Thanks.  This perfectly explains why I can't access my static files when using the '/' pattern.  But its still a mystery as to why the '/channel1/*' doesn't capture requests to '/channel1/{id}/{...} ... i appreciate your help in any case

Comment: Maybe the wrong `<dispatcher>` is been used. If you want to hook on "normal requests", use `REQUEST` (default), if you want to hook on internal forwards only, use `FORWARD`, if you want to hook on includes only, use `INCLUDE`.

Comment: hmm it looks like its just that the pattern "/channel/*" isn't working.  As a test I added the mapping "/channel1/1/test", then when I visited the url it worked!  This is weird..is there any way to do wildcard matching in the url-mapping?

Comment: `/channel/*` doesn't cover `/channel1/foo/bar`, only `/channel/foo/bar`. Use `/channel1/*`.

Comment: that was just a typing error...see the answer I just posted for what the problem was.  Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 3):

The best practice of doing things for rest format is to keep all your URL's which need to be processed by the `DispatcherServlet` in a separate namespace like `web`, so that the static resources will just be served directly and all your controller urls will be passed through Dispatcher, here is an example..

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>web</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>namespace</param-name>
        <param-value>web</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/web-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>web</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/web/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: starting application URLs with /app/ is also common.