# What is wrong about my embedded jetty spring web application configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jetty

I have a spring application that uses an embedded Jetty instance. Since I am programmatically defining my web.xml, here is how I am adding the dispatcher.

```
    DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet();
    dispatcherServlet.setContextClass(
            AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.class);

    ServletHolder holder = new ServletHolder(dispatcherServlet);
    holder.setInitOrder(1);

    ctx.addServlet(holder, "/example/*");
```

At the Jetty level I am defining my spring contexts. The initparams are then applied to the Jetty Context.

```
initParams.put("contextConfigLocation",
        "classpath*:resources/spring/*.xml");
...
ctx.setInitParams(initParams);
```

I do see in the log that it is finding a controller I annotated with @Controller, so I am led to believe that the spring application contexts are loading correctly.

> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/example/helloWorld] onto handler [example.controllers.HelloWorldController]

in my context i have the following for view resolution

```
<!-- Resolves view names to protected .jsp resources within the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

here is my HelloWorldController

```
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping("/example/helloWorld")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {
             ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("helloWorld");
             mav.addObject("message", "Hello World!");
            return mav;
    }
}
```

When I point my browser to it "http://localhost:8080/example/helloWorld, I get the following error in the log.

> org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/example/helloWorld] in DispatcherServlet with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet-1352529649'

I am not sure if I am setting up the jetty container right, or if I am passing in the dispatcher appropriately to the container. Something is off. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045384/spring-mvc-mapping-problem/2045422#2045422

Comment: i updated the @RequestMapping to be just /helloWorld and i guess it seems to be trying to point to the right spot. but i am getting a 404 /WEB-INF/jsp/helloWorld.jsp not found. but the file does exist there. I am not seeing anything in the logs. i am assuming that this is the case because WEB-INF is a protected resource?

Comment: It should work. Show the complete Jetty initialization code.

Comment: The issue was we were configuring a resourceBase for Jetty that was different than the location in which our JSPs were. We weren't using JSP's orginally. After I saw that, i moved the location of the JSPs to the resource directory. This resolved the issue. Although this presents a security issue, but thats another topic ;). Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was we were configuring a resourceBase for Jetty that was different than the location in which our JSPs were. We weren't using JSP's orginally. After I saw that, i moved the location of the JSPs to the resource directory. This resolved the issue. Although this presents a security issue, but thats another topic.