# "No mapping found for HTTP request" when I change the path for DispatcherServlet

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm making my first steps in Spring MVC, and I'm probably missing something, since this doesn't make sense to me:

I started with the [mvn-basic](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/mvc-basic/trunk/) spring sample, and got it to run. Then I wanted to see if I can make it work on a sub-path, so that I can use it alongside legacy code that I have. I made the following changes:

In servlet-context.xml:

```
-   <mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="welcome"/>
+   <mvc:view-controller path="/web/" view-name="welcome"/>
```

In AccountController.java:

```
-@RequestMapping(value="/account")
+@RequestMapping(value="/web/account")
```

In web.xml:

```
-       <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
+       <url-pattern>/web/*</url-pattern>
```

I also increased the logging to DEBUG. I rebuilt and tried running, but trying to access http://localhost:8080/web/account resulted in 404, and "**No mapping found**" in the log, even though earlier in the log I can see "**Mapped URL path [/web/account] onto handler 'accountController'**".

I discovered that if I undo the changes to web.xml, everything works, but then the DispatcherServlet takes over all the requests.

So I have two questions:

1. What am I doing wrong? How can I limit the DispatcherServlet to a subsection of the site?
2. How does it even work in the first place? The demo seems to only send requests to "/" to the DispatcherServlet, so how come "/account" also works?

I'm using Spring 3.0.5.RELEASE

**UPDATE**: The solution is to leave the request mapping is at was, thanks @axtavt. Otherwise the URL becomes http://localhost:8080/web/web/account (notice the duplicate `/web`). I would still like an answer to my second question, though.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045384/spring-mvc-mapping-problem

Comment: Oops, I was sure I checked for that option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this setting:

```
 <url-pattern>/web/*</url-pattern>
```

and

```
 <mvc:view-controller path="/web/" view-name="welcome"/>
```

and

```
  @RequestMapping(value="/web/account")
```

The URLs accessible are:

http://localhost:8080/web/web/        --> as defined as  view-controller config
http://localhost:8080/web/web/account  --> as defined in the controller request mapping

If you want to access account page as /web/account only, redefine your request mapping to:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/account")
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need to do any modification

In servlet-context.xml:
and 
web.xml:

if you want your path to be "/web/account" then your request mapping will be

@RequestMapping(value="/web/account")

and you need call it with "account" if you are already in web (for example http://localhost/urproject/web/currentpage) directory when you call the view 
if your directory is not in web (for example http://localhost/urproject/currentpage) then call it with "/web/account"

I hope that helps